# Javascript: How do I focus the YT search bar?

Tags: javascript

I use a javascript to set the focus / cursor into the first input element.
It works fine under almost all circumstances, but not on the following page:

```
https://www.youtube.com/
```

The textbox that I expected to get the focus is this one:
[image]

It has the following selector (copied from Chrome):

```
#search
```

This is its Xpath:

```
//*[@id="search"]
```

Full XPath:

```
/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div[1]/div[1]/input
```

And this is its code:

```
<input id="search" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="search_query" tabindex="0" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Suchen" aria-label="Suchen" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false" aria-autocomplete="list" dir="ltr" class="ytd-searchbox" style="outline: none;">
```

However, I didn't manage to select this search box.

What am I missing?

This is the javascript code:

```
function pSetFocus()
{
  var element = document.querySelector("*[autofocus]");
  if (element)
  {

  }
  else
  {
     element = document.querySelector("form input:not([type=hidden])");
  }

  if (element)
  {

  }
  else
  {
     element = document.querySelectorAll("#search.ytd-searchbox"); //Here is try to select the YT search bar...
  }

  if (element)
  {

  }
  else
  {
     return;
  }

  element.selectionStart = element.selectionEnd = element.value.length;
  element.focus();
  var y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
  window.scroll(
  {
     top: y,
     behavior: "smooth"
  });
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you writing a userscript?

Comment: `document.querySelector('input#search').focus()` works for me

Comment: @ggorlen I can simply add javascript to my CEF3 based browser.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you! It does for me, too. There must be a bug somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Note that YouTube is using some sort of framework that results in duplicate IDs. Unlike most pages, simply using the ID and assuming that it's unique isn't enough. Sometimes you have to be more precise. Eg `.querySelector('#search')` won't work. Pretty weird setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out another (the most important) problem:

I feed my [CEF3 based browser](https://www.webkitx.com/doc/light/WebKitXCEF3Lib%7EWebKitXCEF3%7EEval.html) the function code itself, but I did not call it.

I am now using

```
Me.webkitx1.Eval(somecodeWithoutFunctionDeclaration)
```

It works.

Before, I used:

```
Me.webkitx1.Eval(somecodeWithFunctionDeclaration)
```

Here you see how I stripped the function header (which made it work for me):

```
  var element = document.querySelector("*[autofocus]");
  if (element)
  {

  }
  else
  {
     element = document.querySelector("form input:not([type=hidden])");
  }

  if (element)
  {

  }
  else
  {
     element = document.querySelector("#search"); 
  }

  if (element)
  {

  }
  else
  {
     return;
  }

  element.selectionStart = element.selectionEnd = element.value.length;
  element.focus();
  var y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
  window.scroll(
  {
     top: y,
     behavior: "smooth"
  });
```